# Are there any downsides to using only @x3 images on an iOS app?

Tags: ios8

Are there downsides for using only @x3 images, 
showing the same images on both @x2 devices (iphone 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 6) and @x3 devices (6+)

i guess it means resizing on the fly.

or should i use @x1 @x2 and @x3?

thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the iPhone 6 uses 2x graphics - I would include both 2x and 3x if you wish to support the iPhone 6+

Comment: thanks, i edited. regarding the question: why not use just @x3 and let the ios do the dirty work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only use @x3 images, the downside is that iOS will have to "do the dirty work".

So your app will be a little bit slower as the system will have to scale your images for @x2/@x1 devices

Also your screens might look less sharp as odd pixels in @x3 don't scale down nicely.

Since @x1 devices are almost a thing of the past (just the iPad mini 1 is on sale, as I write this), its worth considering dropping @x1. @x2 devices will probably be sold for a few more years so I'd keep using @2x.

Answer (score 1):

Only advantage you gain if you only add @x3 images is your apps bundle size may reduce. But IMO scaling down images every time your app runs will definitely impact your performance (based on how image heavy your app is).
I fully agree with Fraser that you may take a decision to drop @1x images (based on your target market segment).