# What points and pixels to use for iOS Game?

Tags: ios, photoshop

I have three characters and one background for an iOS game. I'm using Photoshop to develop these assets. Do I need to develop all the characters and background in @3x and then use the option in Photoshop to make the same image @2x? What would the PPI for each asset be?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only @3x images, iOS will have to resize to fit.

Two possible downsides are, (1) it definitely takes time, (2) image quality may not be what you want. Advantage is that the app bundle size may be smaller.

Now, these downsides above are clearly app dependent (image size, etc.). You can examine with the real device and see how it works.

But usually, we don't have many kinds of real devices. So to have both @3x and @2x is the safe bet. See other comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084793/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-only-x3-images-on-an-ios-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and Apple's guidline [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/). Screen resolution is found at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html) Apples doc.